# Emulator that shows underlying APDU communication between Mobile-phone terminal and UICC

Tags: simulation, emulator, phone, smart-card

Is anyone aware of an emulator that shows the underlying APDU communication between the Mobile phone terminal and the UICC? I'm not talking about SIM tracers or about the standard Android emulators, but an emulator which shows the actual APDU communication between the emulated phone and the SIM card. The emulator should basically show all the terminal-UICC communications like: SELECT EF/DF, READ BINARY/ READ RECORDS, etc.